# Elements are getting skipped while adding them to a list in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice

I'm processing some images an copying them to a location in multiple threads. As part of processing, I'm also adding them to a list.

The list (in which I'm adding the images paths) is missing so many elements. I processed around 2000 images and the list got only 3.

Here are a few relevant snippets of my code:

ImageHelper.java

```
public class ImageHelper {

    private static List<String> filePaths = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

    public synchronized static List<String> getFilePaths(){
        return filePaths;
    }
}
```

ImageProcessRunnable.Java

```
public class ImageProcessRunnable implements Runnable {

    FObject action;
    ImageHelper imageHelper = new ImageHelper();

    public ImageProcessRunnable(FObject action) throws IOException {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {   
                    String filePath = imageProcessor.processImage(file, materialNumberImgName,
                            ImageHelper.getTempLocation(), ImageHelper.getBoxLocation(), idA2A2, logReport);
                    // I do get all the file paths in the above line from image processor.
                    ImageHelper.getFilePaths().add(filePath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ImageService.java

```
public class ImageService {

List<FObject> list = new Vector<FObject>(results);

public static void loadImages() throws IOException {
        try {           
            SessionContext session = SessionContext.getContext(); 
            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);

            for (FObject action : list) {
                if (action instanceof FObject) {    
                    Runnable run = new ImageProcessRunnable(action);
                    SessionThread th=new SessionThread(run, session);
                    pool.execute(th);
                }
                System.out.println("List Size is: "+ImageHelper.getFilePaths().size());
            }
            pool.shutdown();
            if (pool.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                pool.shutdownNow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code is processing and copying all the image to the drive, but it's just not adding all of them to the filePaths list.

Comment: Check your ImageHelper class. Here you just synchronize the get call, but all inserts on the list will still be in parallel. Try to use this Pattern: https://refactoring.com/catalog/encapsulateCollection.html

Comment: But it;s a Collections.synchronizedList.

Comment: There is a lot of code here that you did not show, but at a guess it's taking longer for you to process the threads (`ImageProcessRunnable`) than the 2 seconds of shutdown time you give it.  Get a `Future` from the executor, and wait on all of them to finish before shutting down.

Comment: Will try future. But even in this case it will first call pool.shutdown(); and as per my understanding pool.shutdown() will wait for all the threads to finish.

Comment: No it does not wait.  Read the docs. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown() **"This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that."** Right there in giant black and white letters.

Comment: thanks, btw, even if I change it from 2 seconds to 2 hours. The list always has just 3 items in it. There are total 2000 images I'm processing.